# Third level menu doesn't display - TYPO3

Tags: templates, typo3, typoscript

I'm a TYPO3 Newbie and I tried creating a menu with 3 levels. The 3rd level doesn't display. This is the TypoScript I used:

```
temp.navigation = HMENU
temp.navigation {       
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="expand_menu dropdown">|</li>
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="expand_menu dropdown">|</li>
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
    }
    2 = TMENU
    2 {
        NO = 1
        NO.allWrap = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        IFSUB = 1
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items test12345">|</div></div>
        IFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toogle" data-toogle="dropdown"
        ACTIFSUB = 1
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
        wrap = <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a><div class="row submenu_row"><div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2"><div class="row submenu">|</div></div></div>
    }
    3 = TMENU
    3 {
        N0 = 1
        NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
        ACT = 1
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
        wrap = <ul class="sub_menu">|</ul>
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add `expAll = 1` to the 2nd level menue, too.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
temp.navigation = HMENU
temp.navigation {   
    1 = TMENU
    1 {
        expAll = 1
        wrap = <ul class="nav navbar-nav">|</ul>
        NO = 1
        NO {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        }
        ACT < .NO
        ACT {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        }
        IFSUB < .NO
        IFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="expand_menu dropdown">|</li>
        }
        ACTIFSUB  < .NO
        ACTIFSUB {
            wrapItemAndSub = <li class="expand_menu dropdown">|</li>
        }
    }
    2 < temp.navigation.1
    2 {
        wrap = <a class="dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"></a><div class="row submenu_row"><div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2"><div class="row submenu">|</div></div></div>
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items test12345">|</div></div>
        IFSUB.ATagParams = class="dropdown-toogle" data-toogle="dropdown"
        ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <div class="col-lg-3"><div class="align-items">|</div></div>
        ACTIFSUB.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }
    3 < temp.navigation.1
    3 {
        wrap = <ul class="sub_menu">|</ul>
        NO. wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        ACT.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
        ACT.ATagTitle.field = abstract // description // title
    }
}
```

Your wrapping output is strange HTML for a navigation as UL. Result for valid and accessible menu has to be like this:

```
<ul class="nav-level1">
    <li><a href="...">ItemLevel1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">ItemLevel1</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">ItemLevel1</a>
        <ul class="nav-level2">
            <li><a href="...">ItemLevel2</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">ItemLevel2</a></li>
            <li><a href="...">ItemLevel2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="...">ItemLevel1</a></li>
</ul>
```